# How Can I Make VS Code Split Long Strings *Properly* When I Break Them Up?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

In other editors if I have a line of Javascript like:

```
const longString = 'abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc';
```

and my cursor is in the middle of that string:

```
const longString = 'abc abc abc abc abc |abc abc abc abc';
```

and I hit `ENTER`, my editor will be smart enough to break that string into two valid strings, joined by a `+`:

```
const longString = 'abc abc abc abc abc ' +
                   'abc abc abc abc';
```

... but not VS Code.  The most advanced editor I've ever used can't do this one (seemingly) basic thing, and it's driving me crazy.

Now there *is* a plug-in called Split Lines, that promises to do just this ... but it's been broken for awhile.

My question is, is there any way, in 2023 (ideally with just VS Code, but if not, with extensions) to make VS Code smarter when I break up strings?

Comment: this is a rather specific and subjective definition of "properly". Particularly, your desire for indentation to continue from the column of the first opening of the string is a _preference_ and not a universal law.

Comment: Indentation is irrelevant, as it can be handled by the VS Code formatter (eg. Prettier for JS).  I just want the functionality of turning `'abc'` into `'ab' + 'c'` if I hit enter while the cursor is between "b" and "c".  That is "proper" in the sense that if you don't do it, you wind up with a broken string.

Comment: if strings follow a specific pattern, you can use the Find and Replace feature in VS Code with regular expressions

Comment: Sure ... or I can just type `'` `+` `ENTER` `'` manually ... but this seems like something VS Code should be able to handle.  Competitors like Webstorm do it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use keybindings to achieve this. Add the below `json` into your `keybindings.json`.

```json
{
    "key": "shift+enter",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "args": {
        "snippet": "' + \n'",
        "langId": "javascript",
        "name": "Split Lines"
    }
}
```

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_assign-keybindings-to-snippets

**Note:** Please be aware that this method comes with several tradeoffs in comparison to using extensions.

Comment: Thanks, but in other editors (eg. Webstorm) you can just hit `ENTER`, you don't need to define a separate keyboard macro, and trigger it with a special keyboard command.  Is that possible in VS Code?

Answer (score -5):

You could replace the single quotes with back ticks and it will still be recognized as a single string.

```js
console.log(`string text line 1
string text line 2`);
// "string text line 1
// string text line 2"
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#multi-line_strings

Comment: how does this answer the problem

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion: it doesn't solve things, but it sort of avoids the problem in a way.  Unfortunately I'd create strings with massive amounts of extra whitespace if I did this though.