# Visual Studio Code Editor: Split long string into multiple lines automatically

Tags: visual-studio-code

I need to adhere to a strict right-margin and not have long lines.

I also need to have long text strings as variables.

How can I get VS code to *automatically* split long strings over multiple lines with a `+` concatenator.

For example:

```
string s = "This would be a very long string..."
```

gets turned into

```
string s = "This would be " +
           "a very long string..."
```

I tried the "Prettier" extension but it doesn't seem to want to touch strings.

If there is an editor that can do this I would consider swapping, since for this project I need to do this a lot.

Comment: Does word wrapping not work for you?

Comment: Maybe VS Code extension "Paste and indent" may be of some help.

Comment: you have to write your own custom extension to traverse the file and modify it. When should the split happen, while you are typing the string? Where to split the string, what is a string (many languages have strange string separators, I have written a string searcher for the Remove Comment extension), When is it a long string? ....

Comment: potential duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/70148625/11107541. if it's not a duplicate, explain why. if it is a duplicate, close your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment from @rioV8 seems to be the correct answer.

I made an extension for my specific use case at https://github.com/andybeak/string-breaker-vscode-extension

Comment: still waiting on an explanation of how this question is not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/70148625/11107541