# How can I auto-insert a linebreak with quotation marks into a string in vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have seen the following in a Python tutorial.
Instead of Visual Studio Code they use PyCharm (see pictures).

From this:

[image: Before newline]

After pressing enter at ***p*** to this:

[image: After insert newline]

> It therefore automatically generates a line break ("\") and converts
> the text into a character string with quotation marks.

Is there any option/shortcut/extension to achieve this in Visual Studio Code?
(I am on a Windows with Visual Studio Code)

Comment: Technically, that's an escape character that causes the python interpreter to ignore the line break.

Comment: tangential, but I would typically create a long string from a list of short strings then use `join()`

Comment: I don't think my question was understood correctly. I am looking for an option in visual-studio-code that automatically generates the corresponding output with a shortcut or extension, such as pressing enter. In the picture, for example, pressing enter automatically inserts a new line and the text is enclosed in quotation marks. However, this was done on a Mac and PyCharm. I wonder if this option is also available in VScode and under Windows.

Comment: It looks like PyCharm is just more intelligent about breaking strings up.  Maybe there's a plugin for VSCode that helps but I'm not familiar with those.

Comment: @JonSG that would certainly work, and might be better in some circumstances.  But Python is more than willing to concatenate string literals so there's no reason not to take advantage of it.

Comment: @MarkRansom Sure thing, I tend to shy away from the line continuation feature though. Perhaps that is just my aesthetic though.

Comment: you can define a key binding to act on press of backslash to insert an `"`,  Enter key and `"`

Comment: @rioV8 most of the time a backslash doesn't mean you're creating a new line.  To do this properly requires triggering on the enter key and knowing that you're inside a string.

Comment: then bind to `Ctrl+BackSlash` and press that when You are in a string, what do you want if you want to type a windows path with backslashes

Comment: related to / potential dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/70148625/11107541 (though different language)

Comment: @JonSG, there's no need in `join()`, take a lok at the second option (using parens) here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10660443/9288580

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/discussions/4155

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding @starball's reply in the comments section, I found the appropriate behavior I wanted.

I have carried out the following steps:

1. In vscode press `Ctrl+Shift+P` with the Preferences: `Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)`. This opens the `keybindings.json`
2. Insert the following json:

```
{
    "key": "shift+enter",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "args": {
        "snippet": "'\\\n'",
     // "snippet": "\"\\\n\"",
        "langId": "python",
        "name": "Split Lines"
    }
}
```

Pressing `shift+enter` automatically inserts a new line and the text is enclosed in quotation marks.

Comment: Of course if you defined your string with double quotes `"` your insertion of single quotes `'` is going to mess up big time.

Comment: For this reason, I have also added a second snippet that is commented out. This will trigger double quotes instead of single quotes when you press Shift+Enter.  I only left this solution because it fits my question and the pictures.

Comment: I'm guessing PyCharm is smart enough to use the same kind of quotes the string itself is using, automatically.

Comment: Yes, I think so too. I have now suggested this solution because I have not found any other alternative to this behavior in vscode, such as an extension.